# Correct way to build a tooltip

Tags: css, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, tooltip

All:

Could anyone show me some best practice about tooltip design, the tooltip in my project is like(I am currently using D3.js):

> [1] It can be used across multiple charts, accepting html string
> passed to it
>
> [2] It need to be correctly position no matter if the
> viewport has scale transformation applied or not

That is it.  Thanks for help( modulized plugin-style is appreciated, event better if this tooltip can be a AngularJS directive)

Comment: Did you try anything ? And have you looked at d3tip ?

Comment: @Vishal Kumar Verma   Thanks, I came from d3tip,  the problem about  it is I do not how to handle the scale( when I apply a scale transform to the element, the tooltip can not correctly position)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Angular UI Bootstrap tooltips. You can find their documentation [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).